# Getting an Array From Parse into a Table View (Swift 2)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to pull an array of strings in the from "my_classes" in the "User" class in Parse. I want each individual string within the array to become a separate cell in a tableview when I tap on the search button. This is my array in "my_classes" : ["Physics","Economics","Pre Calculus"]. I want "Physics" as it's own cell, "Economics" as its own cell, etc.

---

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class CardSetClassTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    // MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    @IBOutlet var resultsTableView: UITableView!


    // MARK: Variables

    var searchResults = [String]()


    // MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func newClassBarButtonItemPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("newClassSegue", sender: self)

    }



    // MARK: Functions

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.searchBar.delegate = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {

        if reachabilityStatus == kNOTREACHABLE {

            self.displayAlert("No Internet Connection", message: "Please connect to the internet before continuing.")

        } else {

            searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
            print("Search word = \(searchBar.text!)")

            let classNameQuery = PFQuery(className:"_User")
            classNameQuery.whereKey("my_classes".lowercaseString, equalTo: searchBar.text!.lowercaseString)


            let query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([classNameQuery])



            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if error != nil {

                   self.displayAlert("Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)

                    return
                }

                if let objects = results {

                    self.searchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                    for object in objects {

                        let className = object.valueForKey("my_classes") as! String


                        self.searchResults.append(className)


                    }

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.resultsTableView.reloadData()
                        self.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

                    }



                }




            }



        }

    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return searchResults.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)


        cell.textLabel!.text = searchResults[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {



        let classIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(classIndexPath)! as UITableViewCell

        let spinningActivity = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
        spinningActivity.labelText = "Loading"



        if reachabilityStatus == kNOTREACHABLE {

            spinningActivity.hide(true)

            self.displayAlert("No Internet Connection", message: "Please connect to the internet before continuing.")


        } else {

            // let className : String = String(selectedCell.textLabel!.text!)

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("addCardSet", sender: self)

        }


        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following...

**Edit**

```
 var songsArray = [String]()

 func fetchUsers() {
let userQuery: PFQuery = PFUser.query()!

//search users by the sepcified username, returns a users! object
//make an array to put the values from the users! array object into
//then append those from your "middle-man" array into your destination array,     
//in this example songArray is destination array and songsFromParse is "middle-man" array

userQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: (username)!)
userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
    (users, error) -> Void in

    var songsFromParse = users!

    if error == nil {
        if songsFromParse.count != 0 {

      self.songsArray = (songsFromParse[i].valueForKey("CurrentSongURLArray") as! Array)
            }


        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        print(error)
    }
 })
}
```

You then take your new array that contains the objects that you retrieved, in this example `songsArray` and use it to populate your tableView. In cellForRowAtIndexPath ...

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell ID")
cell?.textLabel?.text = songsArray[indexPath]
return cell!
}
```

Comment: p.s if this worked for you, please check off and accept answer :)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to get a query of songs from each user. I am trying to pull an array of strings from "my_classes" from only one user.

Comment: Oh ok i see, I just edited my answer. Now you search by a specified `username` and then retrieve the `[Array]` that you want by specifying its `valueForKey` which is whatever you named the column in Parse